# How can I run a Principal Component Analysis on data I have just accumulated in Python Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pca

I have a series of functions that process some input data from a .csv file (which is composed of set of DNA sequences). I open the input file, extract the DNA sequences into a dict (called folder_contents in this example), and then take each DNA sequence to be processed by all the functions. The results are stored in a Pandas dataframe in the following code:

```
def data_assembler(folder_contents):
    df= DataFrame(columns= ['Column1','Column2','Column3])
    for candidate in folder_contents.keys()[:50]:
        score1= calculate_complex_mfe(folder_contents[candidate][3])
        score2= calculate_complex_ensemble_defect(folder_contents[candidate][3])
        score3= calculate_GC_content(folder_contents[candidate][1])
        df.loc[candidate]= [score1, score2, score3]
    df= df.sort(['score3'], ascending=False)
    df.to_csv(path.join(output, "DNAScoring.csv"))
```

After having assembled this output data, I wanted to run a PCA in order to calculate the Eigenvalues of each scoring parameter and compare the influence of parameters on their data to each other. I have tried doing this by implementing:

```
from matplotlib import mlab

###data assembler function
pca= mlab.PCA(df, standardize=True)
df= df.sort(['score3'], ascending=False)
df.to_csv(path.join(output, "DNAScoring.csv"))
```

And although a PCA object is made, I cannot seem to view its contents, or get it to print the values in a new column in my Pandas dataframe. I know that there are several packages that are capable of performing PCA on a dataframe, so I am trying to find which approach is the most appropriate for my dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

I usually did PCA reprojections with the PCA implementation included with scikit-learn, so I am not familiar with matplotlib's PCA, however I think that **your problem is trivial**: you are saving your PCA-reprojected data in the `pca` variable, but then **you save to csv the original `df` DataFrame...**

Check if `pca` is still a DataFrame and go with

```
pca.to_csv(path.join(output, "DNAScoring.csv"))
```

**Edit:
Reading [these](https://www.clear.rice.edu/comp130/12spring/pca/pca_docs.shtml) docs i fear that you are misusing this class**: you need a data matrix as input, and since you are constructing a PCA object when you do `pca= mlab.PCA(df, standardize=True)`, **inside the `pca` variable you have a PCA object. Try to read those docs to better understand if you can do what you want to do with this PCA class.**

If you can't do what you want to do, i suggest you to have a look to the scikit-learn (sklearn) library at http://scikit-learn.org

In particular, see the docs for [sklearn.decomposition.PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html)

Comment: I have tried to implement your idea, but then an error is yielded `AttributeError: PCA instance has no attribute 'S' `. So my pca object has to be projected in a different way

Comment: have you checked that pca is still a dataframe? It could be a numpy data matrix maybe...

Comment: I looked into the different attributes that can actually be used with the PCA object, and am still having a difficult time figuring out which values I need to get. What I want to get are the Eigenvalues, or the sum of all the weights multiplied by their corresponding datapoints. Is it possible to get such data from the matlab package?

A good description of such numbers can be seen here at 14:50: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_UVHneBUBW0&t=784s